# Undefined reference to memcpy_s

Tags: c, memcpy, undefined-reference, c11, tr24731

I'm trying to fix an undefined reference to `memcpy_s()` error. I've included `string.h` in my file and the `memcpy()` function works okay, and I've also tried including `memory.h`. I'm on x64 Windows 7 and using gcc 4.8.1 to compile.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void doMemCopy(char* buf, size_t buf_size, char* in, int chr) {
    memcpy_s(buf, buf_size, in, chr);
}
```

memory for `buf` has been allocated in the main function, which calls `doMemCpy(buf, 64, in, bytes)`. `in` is a string read from standard input

Exact error from cmd terminal:

> undefined reference to "memcpy_s" collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: have both `buf` and `in` been allocated? What is the exact error you get? Show the context where you call the function

Comment: `buf` has been allocated in the main() function, and `in` is a string read from standard input. The error I got was `undefined reference to "memcpy_s" collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: new information should be added to the question. please add the info from your comment to your question.

Comment: @jhinzmann not required. It is unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: is it trying to link to a wrong version?

Answer (score 14):

GCC 4.8 does not include the function `memcpy_s`, or any of the other _s bounds checking functions as far as I can tell.  These functions are defined in ISO 9899:2011 Annex K and they are optional to implement.  Before using them you must check if `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` is defined.

These functions were originally implemented by Microsoft and many parties objected to including them in the standard. I think the main objection is that the error handling that is done by the functions involves a global callback handle that is shared between threads, but they are also quite inefficient.

Further reading is available from Carlos O'Donell and Martin Sebor in [Updated Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1969.htm).

Answer (score 5):

I've never used this, but AFAIK, you need to add

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
```

before

```
#include <string.h>
```

to use `memcpy_s()`.

Comment: Would this also require a `-std=c11` compile option?

Comment: Nope. That's for C11.

Comment: @FredLarson it seems so from the reference that you provided. `memcpy_s` is since c11.

Comment: Quoting from the above reference, _As all bounds-checked functions, memcpy_s is only guaranteed to be available if __STDC_LIB_EXT1__ is defined by the implementation and if the user defines __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ to the integer constant 1 before including string.h._ the definition that you stated should be before the line `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish: I'd probably define that on the compile line too: `-DSTDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1=1`

Comment: I included `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1` before `#include <string.h>` and I'm still getting the same error. When I try compiling it with `-std=c11` I get `warning: implicit declaration of function "memcpy_s" [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]` in addition to the undefined reference error

Comment: I don't have access to the same compiler, but it seems unlikely that the error has anything to do with headers, defines or even compilation since this is a link time error indicating that it is missing from the library (possibly because it was not compiled to support it).  Unless of course memcpy_s() is a static inline function or macro.