# Building llvm with CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm-clang

I am trying to build LLVM / Clang on Windows 10 pro following the [instruction from llvm](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#usage). I also have followed all suggestions I could find from prior posts and other sites, but still got errors. Thanks for the help.

I tried it with GCC and Visual Studio separately. Below are the tools I used:

- CMake 3.8.0
- MinGW GCC 5.3.0 / Visual Studio 15
- Python 2.7
- LLVM / Clang 4.0 (source files)

Here is what I got:

- I checked the path for tools and I think it's fine
- CMake was able to find the compiler (GCC or Visual Studio) and starts the configuration.
- But there are quite a few files missing for both approahces, only
  different files are missing
- I also tried to add libraries and components to MinGW / msys and Visual Studio installations. But it didn't help.

Below is the log I got for the attempt with GCC:

!

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for errno.h
-- Looking for errno.h - found
-- Looking for execinfo.h
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for link.h
-- Looking for link.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for ndir.h
-- Looking for ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for signal.h
-- Looking for signal.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for sys/dir.h
-- Looking for sys/dir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
-- Looking for sys/param.h - found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for sys/uio.h
-- Looking for sys/uio.h - not found
-- Looking for termios.h
-- Looking for termios.h - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
-- Looking for zlib.h
-- Looking for zlib.h - not found
-- Looking for fenv.h
-- Looking for fenv.h - found
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - found
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT - found
-- Looking for mach/mach.h
-- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
-- Looking for histedit.h
-- Looking for histedit.h - not found
-- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h
-- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h - not found
-- Looking for xar_open in xar
-- Looking for xar_open in xar - not found
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - not found
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace - found
-- Looking for getpagesize
-- Looking for getpagesize - not found
-- Looking for sysconf
-- Looking for sysconf - not found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - not found
-- Looking for setrlimit
-- Looking for setrlimit - not found
-- Looking for isatty
-- Looking for isatty - found
-- Looking for futimens
-- Looking for futimens - not found
-- Looking for futimes
-- Looking for futimes - not found
-- Looking for posix_fallocate
-- Looking for posix_fallocate - not found
-- Looking for sigaltstack
-- Looking for sigaltstack - not found
-- Looking for lseek64
-- Looking for lseek64 - found
-- Looking for mallctl
-- Looking for mallctl - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo
-- Looking for mallinfo - not found
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics - not found
-- Looking for mkdtemp
-- Looking for mkdtemp - found
-- Looking for mkstemp
-- Looking for mkstemp - found
-- Looking for mktemp
-- Looking for mktemp - found
-- Looking for getcwd
-- Looking for getcwd - found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - found
-- Looking for getrlimit
-- Looking for getrlimit - not found
-- Looking for posix_spawn
-- Looking for posix_spawn - not found
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - not found
-- Looking for realpath
-- Looking for realpath - not found
-- Looking for sbrk
-- Looking for sbrk - not found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strerror_r
-- Looking for strerror_r - found
-- Looking for strerror_s
-- Looking for strerror_s - found
-- Looking for setenv
-- Looking for setenv - found
-- Looking for _chsize_s
-- Looking for _chsize_s - not found
-- Looking for _alloca
-- Looking for _alloca - found
-- Looking for __alloca
-- Looking for __alloca - not found
-- Looking for __chkstk
-- Looking for __chkstk - found
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms - found
-- Looking for ___chkstk
-- Looking for ___chkstk - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms - not found
-- Looking for __ashldi3
-- Looking for __ashldi3 - found
-- Looking for __ashrdi3
-- Looking for __ashrdi3 - found
-- Looking for __divdi3
-- Looking for __divdi3 - found
-- Looking for __fixdfdi
-- Looking for __fixdfdi - found
-- Looking for __fixsfdi
-- Looking for __fixsfdi - found
-- Looking for __floatdidf
-- Looking for __floatdidf - found
-- Looking for __lshrdi3
-- Looking for __lshrdi3 - found
-- Looking for __moddi3
-- Looking for __moddi3 - found
-- Looking for __udivdi3
-- Looking for __udivdi3 - found
-- Looking for __umoddi3
-- Looking for __umoddi3 - found
-- Looking for __main
-- Looking for __main - found
-- Looking for __cmpdi2
-- Looking for __cmpdi2 - found
-- Looking for dlopen
-- Looking for dlopen - found
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS_WITHOUT_LIB - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_ATOMICS64_WITHOUT_LIB - Success
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Success
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_GNU_ZERO_VARIADIC_MACRO_ARGUMENTS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_GNU_ZERO_VARIADIC_MACRO_ARGUMENTS_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test HAS_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAS_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Sphinx disabled.
-- Go bindings disabled.
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing:  OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
-- OCaml bindings disabled.
-- LLVM host triple: i686-pc-mingw32
-- LLVM default target triple: i686-pc-mingw32
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG - Success
-- Performing Test C_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP
-- Performing Test C_WCOMMENT_ALLOWS_LINE_WRAP - Failed
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_STRING_CONVERSION_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_WERROR_DATE_TIME - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CXX11
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Success
-- Found PythonInterp: D:/Python27/python.exe (found version "2.7.13")
-- Constructing LLVMBuild project information
-- LLVMHello ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Targeting AArch64
-- Targeting AMDGPU
-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting BPF
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Lanai
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting RISCV
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting SystemZ
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Clang version: 4.0.0
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NO_NESTED_ANON_TYPES_FLAG - Failed
-- SampleAnalyzerPlugin ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- PrintFunctionNames ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- AnnotateFunctions ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- BugpointPasses ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

[edit] I ran mingw32-make and got the following messages:

```
Scanning dependencies of target LLVMDemangle
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Demangle/CMakeFiles/LLVMDemangle.dir/ItaniumDemangle.cpp.obj
[  0%] Linking CXX static library ..\libLLVMDemangle.a
[  0%] Built target LLVMDemangle
Scanning dependencies of target LLVMSupport
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APFloat.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APInt.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/APSInt.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMBuildAttrs.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/ARMWinEH.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Allocator.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BlockFrequency.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/BranchProbability.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/CachePruning.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/circular_raw_ostream.cpp.obj
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.obj
D:\ydyz\resources\llvmfiles\llvm_source\llvm2\lib\Support\Chrono.cpp: In function 'tm llvm::getStructTM(llvm::sys::TimePoint<>)':
D:\ydyz\resources\llvmfiles\llvm_source\llvm2\lib\Support\Chrono.cpp:29:15: error: '::localtime_s' has not been declared
   int Error = ::localtime_s(&Storage, &OurTime);
               ^
lib\Support\CMakeFiles\LLVMSupport.dir\build.make:312: recipe for target 'lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/Chrono.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:495: recipe for target 'lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [lib/Support/CMakeFiles/LLVMSupport.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:150: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Below are the results I got when building it with VS 2017:

```
D:\ydyz\resources\llvm_source\build2>vcvars64
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0.26403.7
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

D:\ydyz\resources\llvm_source\build2>cmake -G "Visual Studio 15" D:\ydyz\resources\llvm_source\llvm2
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.10.25019.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.10.25017/bin/HostX86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Warning: Did not find file Compiler/MSVC-ASM
-- Looking for dirent.h
-- Looking for dirent.h - not found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for errno.h
-- Looking for errno.h - found
-- Looking for execinfo.h
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for link.h
-- Looking for link.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for ndir.h
-- Looking for ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for signal.h
-- Looking for signal.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for sys/dir.h
-- Looking for sys/dir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
-- Looking for sys/param.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for sys/uio.h
-- Looking for sys/uio.h - not found
-- Looking for termios.h
-- Looking for termios.h - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
-- Looking for zlib.h
-- Looking for zlib.h - not found
-- Looking for fenv.h
-- Looking for fenv.h - found
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - found
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT - found
-- Looking for mach/mach.h
-- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
-- Looking for histedit.h
-- Looking for histedit.h - not found
-- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h
-- Looking for CrashReporterClient.h - not found
-- Looking for xar_open in xar
-- Looking for xar_open in xar - not found
-- Looking for arc4random
-- Looking for arc4random - not found
-- Looking for backtrace
-- Looking for backtrace - not found
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace
-- Looking for _Unwind_Backtrace - not found
-- Looking for getpagesize
-- Looking for getpagesize - not found
-- Looking for sysconf
-- Looking for sysconf - not found
-- Looking for getrusage
-- Looking for getrusage - not found
-- Looking for setrlimit
-- Looking for setrlimit - not found
-- Looking for isatty
-- Looking for isatty - not found
-- Looking for futimens
-- Looking for futimens - not found
-- Looking for futimes
-- Looking for futimes - not found
-- Looking for posix_fallocate
-- Looking for posix_fallocate - not found
-- Looking for sigaltstack
-- Looking for sigaltstack - not found
-- Looking for lseek64
-- Looking for lseek64 - not found
-- Looking for mallctl
-- Looking for mallctl - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo
-- Looking for mallinfo - not found
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics
-- Looking for malloc_zone_statistics - not found
-- Looking for mkdtemp
-- Looking for mkdtemp - not found
-- Looking for mkstemp
-- Looking for mkstemp - not found
-- Looking for mktemp
-- Looking for mktemp - not found
-- Looking for getcwd
-- Looking for getcwd - not found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - not found
-- Looking for getrlimit
-- Looking for getrlimit - not found
-- Looking for posix_spawn
-- Looking for posix_spawn - not found
-- Looking for pread
-- Looking for pread - not found
-- Looking for realpath
-- Looking for realpath - not found
-- Looking for sbrk
-- Looking for sbrk - not found
-- Looking for strtoll
-- Looking for strtoll - found
-- Looking for strerror
-- Looking for strerror - found
-- Looking for strerror_r
-- Looking for strerror_r - not found
-- Looking for strerror_s
-- Looking for strerror_s - found
-- Looking for setenv
-- Looking for setenv - not found
-- Looking for _chsize_s
-- Looking for _chsize_s - found
-- Looking for _alloca
-- Looking for _alloca - not found
-- Looking for __alloca
-- Looking for __alloca - not found
-- Looking for __chkstk
-- Looking for __chkstk - not found
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms
-- Looking for __chkstk_ms - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk
-- Looking for ___chkstk - not found
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms
-- Looking for ___chkstk_ms - not found
-- Looking for __ashldi3
-- Looking for __ashldi3 - not found
-- Looking for __ashrdi3
-- Looking for __ashrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __divdi3
-- Looking for __divdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __fixdfdi
-- Looking for __fixdfdi - not found
-- Looking for __fixsfdi
-- Looking for __fixsfdi - not found
-- Looking for __floatdidf
-- Looking for __floatdidf - not found
-- Looking for __lshrdi3
-- Looking for __lshrdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __moddi3
-- Looking for __moddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __udivdi3
-- Looking for __udivdi3 - not found
-- Looking for __umoddi3
-- Looking for __umoddi3 - not found
-- Looking for __main
-- Looking for __main - not found
-- Looking for __cmpdi2
-- Looking for __cmpdi2 - not found
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T - Failed
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Success
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_GNU_ZERO_VARIADIC_MACRO_ARGUMENTS_FLAG
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_GNU_ZERO_VARIADIC_MACRO_ARGUMENTS_FLAG - Failed
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Threads enabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
-- Sphinx disabled.
-- Go bindings disabled.
-- Could NOT find OCaml (missing:  OCAMLFIND OCAML_VERSION OCAML_STDLIB_PATH)
-- OCaml bindings disabled.
-- LLVM host triple: i686-pc-win32
-- LLVM default target triple: i686-pc-win32
-- Using Debug VC++ CRT: MDd
-- Using Release VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using MinSizeRel VC++ CRT: MD
-- Using RelWithDebInfo VC++ CRT: MD
-- Found PythonInterp: D:/Python27/python.exe (found version "2.7.13")
-- Constructing LLVMBuild project information
-- LLVMHello ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Targeting AArch64
-- Targeting AMDGPU
-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting BPF
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Lanai
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting RISCV
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting SystemZ
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Clang version: 4.0.0
-- SampleAnalyzerPlugin ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- PrintFunctionNames ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- AnnotateFunctions ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- BugpointPasses ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/ydyz/resources/llvm_source/build2
```

Comment: Have you tried building it? CMake only generates and manages build files (which seems to have been successful) which you need to run to actually build the program. You might need to run make or look for a generated project file in the folder you invoked cmake from.

Comment: @LivePastTheEnd Yes,  I did run mingw32-make but it was unsuccessful. I will post the message.

Comment: long shot, since I'm not using windows/mingw, but a cursory search seems to show that all the `_s` C interfaces are part of an optional annex of the `c11` standard. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) along with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278172/undefined-reference-to-memcpy-s) SO thread and a related [discussion](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/errno-t-and-strerror-s-td35455.html) from MingGW mailing list.

Comment: @compor - so Cmake expects the c11 annex to be available, but GCC does not implement it? Should I try to modify the camakelists to avoid the use of the annex? That sounds challenging.

Comment: @DavidY cmake does not expect that, but LLVM source does, since it uses that function. MinGW doesn't seem to implement it, but you can verify by asking in the mailing list. I'd look into LLVM compile options and maybe go on with VS.

Comment: @compor I tried the build using VS 2017, but received errors. To fix it I added components to VS to hopefully include the missing files, but it didn't help. I almost have a full installation of VS 2017 now. I also tried it with VS 2015 but I have a partial installation and it didn't work. For both 2015 and 2017 I do have the c++ compiler installed, but it seems there are still some files (seem originally from unix) missing.

Comment: any real answer to this yet? I'm having the same trouble, but it does seem as though I can build with vs2017; just not mingw.

Comment: @compor I was able to configure llvm with visual studio 2015. I then built it with visual studio 2017 since my 2015 expired. It seems to be working.